# How to exclude files by name in a ClearCase find command?

Tags: version-control, clearcase

Using the ClearCase find command, how do I find all files in a directory that do not have the name pom.xml?

I'd like to pass other selection options to the ClearCase find command so I'd prefer not to execute another command.

I am using a RedHat linux version of ClearCase.  I have tried "cleartool find ! -name pom.xml -print" and that does not work.

PS: I do not use ClearCase by choice, it's mandated on my project.  This is one of the reasons I hate it. I've read the man pages several times and see no clear way to do this that works!

Comment: Found a one-line command that do just what you need. See below

Comment: You are back! :-) And from the 'tick' on my answer, this "one-liner" has done the trick. Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to forget the ***-exec*** option of the cleartool find command.

It actually does allow you to execute other commands than cleartool ones, including system ones (like a sh or DOS script).

I know you would "prefer not to execute another command", but if that other system script is part of the exec option of a find command... it can be argued it is still *one* command ;)

So create a simple script like:

(Unix 'print.sh')

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 != $2 ] ; then
  echo $1
fi
```

(windows 'print.bat')

```
@echo off
if not "%1"=="%2" echo "%1"
```

Put that script either in your search directory, or add the script path to your %PATH% or $PATH environment.

And finally, use the find command (with all the [other options](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm) regarding date filtering, branch filtering and so on)

(Unix)

```
cleartool find . -nrec -type f -exec './print.sh $CLEARCASE_PN ./pom.xml'
```

(windows)

```
cleartool find . -nrec -type f -exec "print.bat %CLEARCASE_PN% .\pom.xml"
```

And here you go: "all files in a directory that do not have the name pom.xml".

Note: the '-type f' option of the find command allows you to restrict the search to file names only (not directory names).

Comment: That's fine, except for cases when we're talking about cleartool evaluating thousands of files (in my case, tens of thousands) of files withing a certain directory. I want cleartool to not even look at a particular directory. If I have it evaluate everything and then omit it later with another command, after cleartool is done searching everything, it will take a lot longer to complete.

Answer (score 3):

ClearCase wildcards doesn't have inversion (AFAIR) but you can use grep for this -

```
cleartool ls -short -nxname | grep -v pom.xml
```

Comment: I don't think that was the xml name the OP was using ;-)

Answer (score 3):

There is another solution which might work for you. Try

[ccapply task](http://clearantlib.sourceforge.net/ccapply.html)